# jQuery ajax call for another domain (Cross Site)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've just downloaded this jQuery component: [jquery-xmlrpc](https://github.com/timheap/jquery-xmlrpc) that unfortunately allows you to call xml-rpc methods only within same domain.

I've started to look at code to find if was possible to do some "hack" and allow cross-domain also.
I've found that call

```
return $.ajax(settings);
```

where settings is valued with these parameters

```
settings.dataType = 'xml json';
settings.type = 'POST';
settings.contentType = 'text/xml';
settings.converters = {'xml json': xmlrpc.parseDocument};
```

Now, based on http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ I can see that there's a parameter enabling me to do what I'm looking for: `crossDomain`

So I've added this line of code inside that component

```
settings.crossDomain = true
```

Again, unfortunately, if I open some debug tool like "firebug" I can notice that parameters are posted to my local domain.

For example:

url of my request: https://foo.foobar.com
local domain ulr: http://bar.bar.com
post url: http://bar.bar.com/https://foo.foobar.com

Anyone can point me to the right direction? Maybe I'm messing things up with jQuery as I'm not such experienced and skilled in it?

Comment: You'll need to pull some `jsonp` magic or do it with PHP's `curl` function or equivalent.

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/

Comment: I don't know if is this the problem, of course I know about CORS but is CORS missing that cause the POST to that kind of url?